# Bound on exponential sum with weights

Tags: nt.number-theory, exponential-sums

Let $e(z)$ denote $e^{2 \pi i z}$ and let $f(z)$ a smooth real function.
I know one can bound sums of the form
$$
\sum_{x \leq X} e(f(x))
$$
via for example Van der Corputs's result, provided we make assumptions 
on the range of the derivatives. I was wondering if there were results of this type
for weighted sums. Can we bound a sum of the form 
$$
\sum_{x \leq X} g(x) e(f(x)) ?
$$
If so I was wondering what kind of assumption would be needed for g(z).
(In particular, would it possible for $g(z) = 2^z$, for example? ) Thanks!

Comment: if $g(z)=2^z$, then the last summand should give the dominant contribution to the sum. If $g$ varies slowly, then you can use partial summation. Look also in Titchmarsch and in Iwaniec-Kowalski for various results about exponential sums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use van der Corputs's method for weighted sums as well, see Ch. III in

> Karatsuba A. A., Voronin S. M. The Riemann zeta-function Walter de Gruyter & Co., 1992.

Answer (score 0):

What is the exact result you have in mind? I see that [a lemma of Van der Corput](http://www.tricki.org/article/The_van_der_Corput_lemma_for_oscillatory_integrals) says something about *integrals* of functions which oscillate rapidly enough. In the case of a sum I don't see that you could expect the same cancellation to go on.

At any rate, the link has a result similar to what you want using integration by parts. Whatever is true for sums can probably be similarly generalized by a [summation by parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts) .